# jQuery/AJAX submits but won't delete from the database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm stuck on an issue with my AJAX/jQuery + PHP code, not sure what is going on. My insert page works perfectly fine, but when I try to create a delete event - nothing happens. My code is:

HTML/PHP Snippet

```
<div class="card mb-3">
    <div class="card-header">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
            <span>Notepad</span>
            <span><button class="no-style" id="deleteNotepad"><i class="fa-solid fa-x"></i></button></span>
                 </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body text-center p-0">
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $np['id'];?>" id="notepadId">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="notepad" rows="4"><?php echo $np['notepad']; ?></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

My JS file

```
$("deleteNotepad").on("click", function () {
    var notepadId = $("#notepadId").val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "fetch/delete-notepad.php",
      data: {
        notepadId: notepadId,
      },
      success: function () {
        $("#notepads").load(location.href + " #notepads");
      },
    });
  });
```

and my PHP file

```
<?php 
require('../inc/functions.php');
$notepadId = $_POST['notepadId'];
mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM notepads WHERE id = '$notepadId'");
```

I have tried changing the element id's (not sure if I had multiple), but even the most random string "asdijas87wewq" for example, doesn't work.

I also was looking at the dev console but nothing shows when I click the delete button.

Comment: If you were to modify your PHP so that you `var_dump` the value of `$notepadId` before executing the query, query the database and `var_dump` the result with the query `"SELECT * FROM notepads WHERE id = {$notepadId}"` to see if the entry you are trying to delete exists.

Comment: Your current code is open to SQL Injection, you should use prepared queries to remove this vulnerability.

Comment: Your code requires autocommit=ON, better to explicitly commit, otherwise DELETE statement will be rolled back

Comment: It works directly through PHP by doing `if(isset($_POST['deleteNotepad'])) {` then the same delete code I had for AJAX. So maybe it's something with my jquery code? Hmmm...

Comment: @AndyPreston yeah I am just on a local environment right now, I will update all the code using prepared statements.

Comment: If when you say "the dev console" you mean the JavaScript console in your browser, then there'll be nothing of an use there. The delete is being handled by your PHP/Web server and you need to look in the server logs for any useful error messages.

Comment: Makes sense, is there a log within xampp or is it something I would have to create...

EDIT: I found it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add # in your selector

```
$("deleteNotepad").on("click", function () {
```

Should be

```
$("#deleteNotepad").on("click", function () {
```

Comment: Thank you for that. I apologizing for wasting time - forgot the # -_-.